# how Send multi contacts in one message in whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp, whatsapi

I use wwebjs to send messages but I'm confused about how to send messages to all the numbers that I captured from the html file

the result is like this 085695036401,081545911622 and not working

please help me

```
const api = async (req, res) => {
    let noHp =  req.body.telpon
    const pesan =  req.body.pesan

try {
if(noHp.startsWith("0")){
    noHp = "62" + noHp.slice(1) +"@c.us"
}else if(noHp.startsWith("62")){
    noHp = noHp + "@c.us"
}else{
    noHp = "62" + noHp + "@c.us"
}
    const user = await client.isRegisteredUser(noHp)
    if(user){
        client.sendMessage(noHp,pesan)
        res.json({status : "Berhasil terkirim", pesan})
    } else{
        res.json({status: "gagal", pesan: "No tidak terdaftar"})
    }
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({status : "error", pesan : "error server"})
}
}
```